# Systemd service cannot open display

Tags: scripts, display, systemd, services, autostart

I am using systemd service to auto-run a shell script when the system boots.the shell script is used to run a python code that code includes cv2 to use the camera and it works fine when the system boots but at the end, I get this error "cannot open display".

the shell script contains:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cd /home/ahmed/darknet-AlexAB-For-Testing/

    python darknet_video.py
```

the service script contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target
Wants=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/ahmed/yolo.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I understand that the problem is related to starting a service that interacts with the display, but I'm stuck on how to enable this so it works on boot. Any suggestions?

Comment: A display is not assigned until after a user logs in. Anything requiring a display before login will fail. Running a display-requiring service as root is generally unwise.

Comment: Is a human going to login to it daily? Or is this like a display?

Comment: a human is going to log in daily.